# problem with joining

Tags: modeling, object-mode

I have created some hair using bezier curves, converted it into a mesh, and am now trying to join it to my main character mesh. I have a small problem: the main character mesh has a mirror modifier, and my hair model is asymmetrical. This makes the final joined model look somewhat off, as the hair model becomes symmetrical when it is not supposed to. Is there any way to join the two objects while ignoring the mirror modifier, or should I try to make a new hair model with the mirror modifier in mind? Also, if it is possible to fix the color change as well, I'd love to know how.[image]

Comment: if you join an object to another one that has a Mirror modifier you won't avoid the Mirror modifier, so you either need to apply the modifier or don't join

Comment: The color of objects in the solid mode 3D viewport can be changed at Object Properties > Viewport Display > Color

Answer (score 0):

Mirror modifiers will mirror the mesh of the *entire object* to which they are applied, so any mesh that is joined in will also be affected by that modifier. Two main alternatives exist to work around your issue.

- Apply the mirror modifier to the main mesh before joining the hair mesh.
- Keep the hair mesh as a separate object and parent it to the body mesh so that it will stay "attached" and transform/scale as such.